# How can I use jetty 9 plug in in maven?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jetty

This works fine:

```
<plugin>                                                     
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>                     
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>              
    <version>8.1.16.v20140903</version>                      
    <configuration>                                          
        <webApp>                                             
            <contextPath>/${project.artifactId}</contextPath>
        </webApp>                                            
        <stopKey>STOP</stopKey>                              
        <stopPort>9999</stopPort>                            
        <scanIntervalSeconds>5</scanIntervalSeconds>         
    </configuration>                                         
</plugin>
```

But I need to use Servlet 3.1 so I need jetty 9. But I can not find it in maven repository. How can I acquire it? I am using IntelliJ as IDE.

Answer (score 1):

The project has been moved to Eclipse Foundation. Now it has different groupId:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.2.3.v20140905</version>
    ...
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the plugin? I want to be able to run jetty inside IntelliJ, adding this dependency does not help.

Comment: I have just modified my above post. Do not add it as a dependency, just replace your current plugin definition with it (change groupId and version). If it won't help, can you please elaborate a little bit more how exactly are you using IntelliJ in this context?

Comment: Hello, it did not. In IntelliJ right handside I see the available Life Cycles and Plugins for maven. When I use what I have in question, there are multiple jetty options available such as run, run-war etc.. With this there is nothing..

Answer (score 0):

Try including the 'version' tag in your pom dependency like,

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.2.3.v20140905</version>
</dependency>
```

And I don't know why you cant find it in maven repo. It right here,

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-maven-plugin/9.2.3.v20140905

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the plugin? I want to be able to run jetty inside IntelliJ, adding this dependency does not help.